# Change mouse behaviour for terminals in XFCE

Tags: vim, terminal, debian, mouse, xfce

I am using Xfce on a Debian system and would like to use the mouse in some terminal applications (like vim).

The problem is that clicking or selecting with the mouse in the terminal is not handed to the application but rather handled by xfce to copy the contents. This breaks the usability of the mouse, as I can not use it to move the cursor or  to follow a tag in vim.

Scrolling in vim with the mouse wheel works fine, probably because that is not catched by xfce. I tried to switch from the default xfce terminal to Xterm, but this did not result in an improvement as the mouse still does not work.

Is there any possibility of changing the behaviour of xfce? I did not find any settings related to this issue.

I do not have administrator rights on this machine, so please do not suggest changing the system considerably.

Comment: short question, have you set `:set mouse=a` in vim?

Comment: Yes I have. As I said scrolling with the mouse wheel works, so I assume that everything is fine with vim's settings.

Comment: is env TERM set correctly, `echo $TERM` ?

Comment: It is set to xterm. The problem is probably related to Xfce, as e.g. a right click opens the XFCE menu for copying and pasting from the terminal.